# Why would the same load csv in neo4j take exponential longer when run a second time (on a clean db)?

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am new to using Neo4j so my first attempting at loading the database was a learning experiment. I realized when I attempted some of the queries I wanted to do, I didn't create the right model. I cleared the database, from the command line, using: rm -rf data/* and started over (after stopping the database and starting it after). The first 3 loads were almost exactly the same as the first time I imported data.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MERGE (p:Provider {pid:line.pid});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MERGE (c:Credential {name:credential});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MATCH (p:Provider {pid:line.pid});
MATCH (c:Credential {name:credential});
MATCH (p)-[:IS_A]->(c);
```

The only difference the second time I ran these load statements, was the first node was given two labels:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MERGE (p:Provider:Person {pid:line.pid});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MERGE (c:Credential {name:credential});

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MATCH (p:Person {pid:line.pid});
MATCH (c:Credential {name:credential});
MATCH (p)-[:IS_A]->(c);
```

The first time I ran these 3 imports, it took maybe 20 minutes. However, the second time, it has been running for 3 days. The first two loads, were still pretty fast, maybe 5 minutes each. It is the relationship that has been running ever since. I can not figure out why it is taking so long.

Comment: I copied my code over wrong for the last load. It should be: USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MATCH (p:Person {pid:line.pid})
MATCH (c:Credential {name:credential})
MERGE (p)-[:IS_A]->(c);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have indexes on the properties?

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(pid)
CREATE INDEX ON :Credential(name)
```

Alternatively, if you want uniqueness to be enforced on the columns you should create a constraint (this also creates an index):

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) ASSERT n.pid IS UNIQUE
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Credential) ASSERT n.name IS UNIQUE
```

Also, I think your last `MATCH` should be a `MERGE`, and you shouldn't have semi-colons:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS from 'file' AS line
WITH line
MATCH
  (p:Person {pid:line.pid}),
  (c:Credential {name:credential})
MERGE (p)-[:IS_A]->(c);
```

Comment: I have uniqueness constraints set up. For Person, I used just the CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Provider) ASSERT n.pid IS UNIQUE, would I need to do that for the Person label as well, i.e. CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) ASSERT n.pid IS UNIQUE? For the last MATCH you are right, its suppose to be a MERGE. That was a copy error.

Comment: I think adding the Person constraint or index would help a lot with performance

Comment: Great thanks! I think thats it. I just needed an index/uniqueness constraint for every label.